# Is GPS Spoofing possible in iOS sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, gps

Is there any way in iOS to spoof the GPS location. I mean to say show user different coordinates not the real one ?

Thanks!

Comment: [`method_setImplementation()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-SW7)

Comment: Do you want to spoof, that means faking GPS signals such that all applications get the wrong positions, Or do you want to mock GPS location in order for test purposes inside your app ?

Comment: @H2CO3 interesting, but this works only in your own app, not on the whole phone. So its not spoofing, only mocking

Comment: @AlexWien [MobileSubstrate](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate)

Comment: @H2CO3 ok, not bad for creating a GPS simulator outside of your app, but only for jailbreaked.

Comment: @AlexWien And for the unjailbroken, there's surely no possibility to hook into another app (gotta love that sandbox), so we're pretty much sorted.

Comment: @H2CO3 and thats fine! For GPS spoofing you need an external device which costs 20.000€

Comment: 20.000€ seems a bit too high. I'm betting it's feasible using a $30 RPi

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know gps gives you lat long and you show it on map.
What you can do is add your code in between to spoof obviously iam not talking about the default app.  Look at [heversine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) formula it will be helpfull

take care of water bodies and buildings you dont want to spoof the position of car in ocean iguess

Comment: Your answer ha snothing to do with spoofing. Spoofing is faking GPS positions. You explained how to mock GPS data for a test setup.

Comment: can i spoof the GPS coordinates for entire device not just the app.. ?

Comment: @AlexWien Faking gps position...for that you need military equipment i suggest what looks iphonly possible

Answer (score 0):

the most easiest way to do that is make the map annotation you own,

you may look that this  https://github.com/samvermette/SVPulsingAnnotationView

hide the original one & make a fake annotation view with any location you want

Comment: hi, can i spoof the GPS coordinates for entire device not just the app.. ?

Comment: no, you can't you can only spoof the user who use your app,  the sandbox mode won't let you to effect iOS system